# Loading Iframe in lightning component, slows down the loading time of page. Any alternative?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, performance

We have many iframes with relative visualforce page urls inside lightning component.
And these all lightning components are displayed on Lightning Sales Console app inside a flexipage. 
This results in slow loading of page inside the iframe.

Is there any alternative to load visualforce page inside a lightning component.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [lightning inspector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm) to see what is causing the delay first.

Comment: I probably know what is causing the delay, as in salesforce documentation its written not to use iframes and if we use relative urls then it tries to redirect multiple times to find the correct base url and that is what takes time.